# Can a faulty cable (or other issue) cause SMART errors with a perfectly good drive?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, smart

On a lot of my drives I get `WRITE|READ FPDMA QUEUED` errors, like so:

```
Error 23 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 43915 hours (1829 days + 19 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 00 d5 67 35 40  Error: WP at LBA = 0x003567d5 = 3499989

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 80 10 70 2d dc 40 00  37d+00:38:20.201  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 60 08 70 67 35 40 00  37d+00:38:17.668  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 20 00 d0 67 35 40 00  37d+00:38:17.668  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 00 de a8 97 40 00  37d+00:38:17.652  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 02 00 c0 68 59 40 00  37d+00:38:17.651  READ FPDMA QUEUED
```

On each of these drives I also notice `Current_Pending_Sector`, `Reallocated_Sector_Ct` and other attributes will be > 0.

I am curious though. Are these errors indicative of a failing drive? If I replace the drive am I not fixing the underlying issue, and will simply face the same problem down the road?

For example, in the post [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20240204171336/https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/550559) it seems that some of these errors are not caused by a failing drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Current_Pending_Sector` and `Reallocated_Sector_Ct` are counters specifically dedicated to tracking *media errors*, but they are not the only attributes denoting issues.

`WRITE/READ FPDMA QUEUED` errors means that a read/write command to a specific LBA was not successful. I saw these errors generated by a multitude of issues, such as:

- bad power supply/cable
- bad SATA cable
- bad motherboards / SATA controllers
- erratic HDD firmware
- overheated HDD microcontrollers

I suggest you to re-seating the cables. If this fails, you can try replacing the affected disk. If the new disk starts reporting the same issue, you have some more fundamental hardware issues.